# HornetQ JMS: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: jar, jms, nosuchmethoderror

unfortunately while trying to get a JMS service working with HornetQ, I am running form error message to error message. The prior error was related to a missing core.jar file.       [Prior Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45189488/hornetq-java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-lorg-hornetq-core-logging-logger/45189589?noredirect=1#comment77393599_45189589)

After all, I am trying to implement a simple producer/consumer example as a jms service. (Based on "HornetQ Messaging Developer's Guide")

```
package chapter01;

import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.naming.NamingException;

public class ECGMessageConsumerProducerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NamingException, JMSException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub


         javax.naming.Context ic = null;
         javax.jms.ConnectionFactory cf = null;
         javax.jms.Connection connection = null;
         javax.jms.Queue queue = null;
         javax.jms.Session session = null;
         com.mongodb.Mongo m;
         com.mongodb.DB db;
         String destinationName = "queue/DLQ";


         java.util.Properties p = new java.util.Properties();
         p.put(javax.naming.Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
         "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
         p.put(javax.naming.Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES,
         "org.jboss.naming:org.jnp.interfaces");
         p.put(javax.naming.Context.PROVIDER_URL, "jnp://localhost:1099");
         ic = new javax.naming.InitialContext(p);


         cf = (javax.jms.ConnectionFactory)ic.lookup("/ConnectionFactory");
         queue = (javax.jms.Queue)ic.lookup(destinationName);
         connection = cf.createConnection();
         session = connection.createSession(false, javax.jms.Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
         connection.start();


         String theECG = "1;02/20/2012 14:01:59.010;1020,1021,1022";
         javax.jms.MessageProducer publisher = session.createProducer(queue);
         javax.jms.TextMessage message =
         session.createTextMessage(theECG);
         publisher.send(message);
         System.out.println("Message sent!");
         publisher.close();





    }

}
```

While facing erros I probably added unneeded jars:

[image: Jars]

However, I get the following error message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.hornetq.api.core.client.ClientSessionFactory.copy()Lorg/hornetq/api/core/client/ClientSessionFactory;
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnectionInternal(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:612)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:116)
    at org.hornetq.jms.client.HornetQConnectionFactory.createConnection(HornetQConnectionFactory.java:111)
    at chapter01.ECGMessageConsumerProducerExample.main(ECGMessageConsumerProducerExample.java:33)
```

I expect the error to be caused by a mismatch between jars used by the server and used by the client. But since I am a programmer noob, I do not really know what exact jars with suitable versions are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Try defining NettyConnectorFactory as connector as in [jboss reference](https://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/configuring-transports.html#d0e3531).

for example in hornetq-configuration.xml file:

```
<connectors>
    <connector name="netty">
        <factory-class>
            org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory
        </factory-class>
        <param key="port" value="5446"/>
    </connector>
</connectors>
```

Comment: the connector was already defined in the non-clustured-standalone config file:   <connectors>
      <connector name="netty">
         <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyConnectorFactory</factory-class>
         <param key="host"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.host:localhost}"/>
         <param key="port"  value="${hornetq.remoting.netty.port:5445}"/>
      </connector>